# Unable to highlight the segment control properly ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using a segment control and when its unselected and user tries to move to next screen , then it should get highlighted.

My code logic:

```
+(void) validateSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl *) segmentControl
{
    // mark invalid field
    segmentControl.layer.cornerRadius=4.0f;
    segmentControl.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    segmentControl.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:175/255.0 green:14/255.0 blue:37/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;
    segmentControl.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
}
```

But the problem is , the red highlight is little out of the segment control. Not sure why it's happening .tried reducing the corner radius but no luck.

here is the image:
[image]

What could be the problem.

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you put image of what you wantand what you tried.

Comment: i tried your code, it worked fine for me (at least based on my understanding of your question), maybe attach a screen shot for your problem...

Comment: have very less point to upload image. Any free site to upload.any suggestion?

Comment: @Lalit_vicky, try gyazo to upload images

Comment: i think you have enough reputation to upload image, it only requires 10 reputation, check this post:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: http://gyazo.com/9c96daae40411ce2097afc458b10d9ce  is the link guys..sorry for delay... thanks mykola for suggesting gyazo

Comment: just added the image for you, and did some tests based on your screen shot, please take a look. hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that, if you divided the width of your segmented controller by the number of your segments, if that returns an integer, all your codes work fine, on the other hand, if that returns a value with decimal places, you will end up the way you have now. For example:

if my segmented controller have 4 segments, and it's total width 240. 240/4 = 60, it's an integer value. After adding border, it looks like this:

[image]

but when i change the width to 250, 250/4 = 62.5, which has decimal places, it becomes like this:

[image]

So i think in your case, the easiest solution would be simply change the width of your segmented control to X, which X = (segment width) * 3, and segment width has to be an integer value.

Hope that helps. and to be honest, i never knew that before this question. And i can't explain why, seems like the SDK renders the segmented control that way.

Comment: great buddy.. it was a nasty problem.. i would have taken ages to solve it...huhhhhhh Thanks man..cheers

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to not to set the width of the segmentedControl manually.  You just  init the segmented control with Items like

```
UISegmentedControl * yourSegmentControl  = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"All", @"Due", @"OverDue", @"Cleared"]];
[yourSegmentControl sizeToFit];
```

this way the segments are automatically adjusted for width depending upon number of elements, leaving you to not to worry about custom width.  This is efficient code as well.

This way, the layer of your component is also well aligned to the actual border.

hope that helps.